# App revamp onboarding suggestions that is low development effort?

Tags: tooltips, onboarding, carousel, redesign, tutorial

I'm working on an app revamp, and due to timeline constraints, I'm figuring out how to best onboard existing users to the newly designed app. Are there any best practices or suggestions to this?

I'm considering – Usual skippable carousel, tooltips, (probably not) walkthroughs, demo video etc. Wondering if you know of any good examples, references or articles on this topic.

If anyone can chime in on some potential:

- problems
- opportunities
- solutions

to this part of the project also would be great!

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered properly.

Comment: https://www.nngroup.com/articles/onboarding-tutorials/